# Python Data Scraping return empty values from the table

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I am trying to scrape data from a website but instead of printing output with data contained in the table it returns an empty string. The website am trying to scrape data from is http://tfda.go.tz/portal/registered-products/registered-drug-products-1

and this is the code I used for my scraping

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import sys, io
page = requests.get("http://tfda.go.tz/portal/registered-products/registered-drug-products-1")
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
sys.stdout = io.TextIOWrapper(sys.stdout.buffer,'cp437','backslashreplace')

#print(soup.prettify())

simple = list(soup.children)
#print(simple)

#S/n = ""
Certificate = ""
Brandname = ""
#Classfication Name = ""
#Dosage Form = ""
#Product Strength = ""
Registrant = ""
#Registrant Country = ""
Manufacturer = ""
#Manufacturer Country = ""
#Expiry Date = ""

table = soup.find("table", { "class" :"table table-stripped table_productDrugs" })
print (table)
```

And here is my output screenshot [sample output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CKEmj.jpg)

I appreciate your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have already noticed that the data are already there in json format which are also visible in the image provided by @Wu Wenter. To fetch them accordingly you neeed to make a `post` request in [this url](http://tfda.go.tz/portal/en/trader_module/trader_module/getRegisteredDrugs_products) along with necessary parameters to pass as `data`. With the usual approach you can get only 20 items. However, I have twitched a little to parse all the entries from there which are `3,911` in number. The below script will fetch you the data from the first five columns.

As it gives you all `3,911` entries from that table, it may take some time to load.

```
import requests

URL = 'http://tfda.go.tz/portal/en/trader_module/trader_module/getRegisteredDrugs_products'
payload = "draw=1&columns%5B0%5D%5Bdata%5D=no&columns%5B0%5D%5Bname%5D=&columns%5B0%5D%5Bsearchable%5D=True&columns%5B0%5D%5Borderable%5D=True&columns%5B0%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bvalue%5D=&columns%5B0%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bregex%5D=False&columns%5B1%5D%5Bdata%5D=certificate_no&columns%5B1%5D%5Bname%5D=&columns%5B1%5D%5Bsearchable%5D=True&columns%5B1%5D%5Borderable%5D=True&columns%5B1%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bvalue%5D=&columns%5B1%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bregex%5D=False&columns%5B2%5D%5Bdata%5D=brand_name&columns%5B2%5D%5Bname%5D=&columns%5B2%5D%5Bsearchable%5D=True&columns%5B2%5D%5Borderable%5D=True&columns%5B2%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bvalue%5D=&columns%5B2%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bregex%5D=False&columns%5B3%5D%5Bdata%5D=classification_name&columns%5B3%5D%5Bname%5D=&columns%5B3%5D%5Bsearchable%5D=True&columns%5B3%5D%5Borderable%5D=True&columns%5B3%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bvalue%5D=&columns%5B3%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bregex%5D=False&columns%5B4%5D%5Bdata%5D=common_name&columns%5B4%5D%5Bname%5D=&columns%5B4%5D%5Bsearchable%5D=True&columns%5B4%5D%5Borderable%5D=True&columns%5B4%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bvalue%5D=&columns%5B4%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bregex%5D=False&columns%5B5%5D%5Bdata%5D=dosage_form&columns%5B5%5D%5Bname%5D=&columns%5B5%5D%5Bsearchable%5D=True&columns%5B5%5D%5Borderable%5D=True&columns%5B5%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bvalue%5D=&columns%5B5%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bregex%5D=False&columns%5B6%5D%5Bdata%5D=product_strength&columns%5B6%5D%5Bname%5D=&columns%5B6%5D%5Bsearchable%5D=True&columns%5B6%5D%5Borderable%5D=True&columns%5B6%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bvalue%5D=&columns%5B6%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bregex%5D=False&columns%5B7%5D%5Bdata%5D=registrant&columns%5B7%5D%5Bname%5D=&columns%5B7%5D%5Bsearchable%5D=True&columns%5B7%5D%5Borderable%5D=True&columns%5B7%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bvalue%5D=&columns%5B7%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bregex%5D=False&columns%5B8%5D%5Bdata%5D=registrant_country&columns%5B8%5D%5Bname%5D=&columns%5B8%5D%5Bsearchable%5D=True&columns%5B8%5D%5Borderable%5D=True&columns%5B8%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bvalue%5D=&columns%5B8%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bregex%5D=False&columns%5B9%5D%5Bdata%5D=manufacturer&columns%5B9%5D%5Bname%5D=&columns%5B9%5D%5Bsearchable%5D=True&columns%5B9%5D%5Borderable%5D=True&columns%5B9%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bvalue%5D=&columns%5B9%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bregex%5D=False&columns%5B10%5D%5Bdata%5D=manufacturer_country&columns%5B10%5D%5Bname%5D=&columns%5B10%5D%5Bsearchable%5D=True&columns%5B10%5D%5Borderable%5D=True&columns%5B10%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bvalue%5D=&columns%5B10%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bregex%5D=False&columns%5B11%5D%5Bdata%5D=expiry_date&columns%5B11%5D%5Bname%5D=&columns%5B11%5D%5Bsearchable%5D=True&columns%5B11%5D%5Borderable%5D=True&columns%5B11%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bvalue%5D=&columns%5B11%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bregex%5D=False&columns%5B12%5D%5Bdata%5D=id&columns%5B12%5D%5Bname%5D=&columns%5B12%5D%5Bsearchable%5D=True&columns%5B12%5D%5Borderable%5D=True&columns%5B12%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bvalue%5D=&columns%5B12%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bregex%5D=False&order%5B0%5D%5Bcolumn%5D=0&order%5B0%5D%5Bdir%5D=asc&start=0&length=3911&search%5Bvalue%5D=&search%5Bregex%5D=False"

with requests.Session() as s:
    s.headers={"User-Agent":"Mozilla/5.0"}
    s.headers.update({'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8'})
    res = s.post(URL, data = payload)

    for data in res.json()['data']:
        serial = data['no']
        certno = data['certificate_no']
        brndname = data['brand_name']
        clssification = data['classification_name']
        common_name = data['common_name']
        print(serial,certno,brndname,clssification,common_name)
```

Output:

```
1 TAN 09,176 N02B MEP Trabilin Human Medicinal Products Tramadol
2 TZ13H188 Melorem 7.5 Human Medicinal Products Meloxicam
3 TAN 00,2246 P01X FAR Diminazen Veterinary Pharmaceutical Diminazene + Phenazone
4 TAN 00,2075 J01D FAR Penstrep 20/25 Veterinary Pharmaceutical Procaine BenzylPenicillin + Dihydrostreptomycin
5 TAN 00,2076 J01A FAR Tridox 20 Veterinary Pharmaceutical Oxytetracycline
6 TAN 00,1820 D01A GLE Supirocin Human Medicinal Products Mupirocin
```

And so on ----

Comment: Thank you I managed to get the same output but will you explain more how you generated that payload so I can generate for couple of pages from the same site.

Comment: What do you mean by `generating couple of pages` because the script should already give you all the items available across multiple pages. There are `3,911` items in that site and the script can fetch you that. As for your question: how to generate payload parameters, just take a look at the answer provided by `Wu Wenter` where he has given an example through an image.

Comment: One more thing: as you seem to be new in this site, please take a look at this link [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers). Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The data in the table is load from  dynamic xhr http request. 
You should use chrome inspect element - network - xhr.
You can find the xhr request.

[image: xhr get]

Comment: This presents data in cleaner json format ,I will use this to copy and paste manually automation proved failure to me

Answer (score 0):

The site is dynamic, thus, you need to use a browser manipulation tool such as `selenium`:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from collections import namedtuple
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
results = namedtuple('results', [u'sn', u'certificate_no', u'brand_name', u'classification_name', u'common_name', u'dosage_form', u'product_strength', u'registrant', u'registrant_country', u'manufacturer', u'manufacturer_country', u'expiry_date'])
d = webdriver.Chrome('/path/to/chromedriver')
d.get('http://tfda.go.tz/portal/registered-products/registered-drug-products-1')
table_results = [i.text for i in soup(d.page_source, 'lxml').find_all('td')]
new_results = table_results[12:]
final_results = [results(*new_results[i:i+12]) for i in range(0, len(new_results), 12)]
```

Output:

```
[results(sn=u'1', certificate_no=u'TAN 09,176 N02B MEP', brand_name=u'Trabilin', classification_name=u'Human Medicinal Products', common_name=u'Tramadol', dosage_form=u'Capsules', product_strength=u'50mg', registrant=u'Acino Pharma AG', registrant_country=u'SWITZERLAND', manufacturer=u'Merckle GmbH', manufacturer_country=u'GERMANY', expiry_date=u'13-10-2019'), results(sn=u'2', certificate_no=u'TZ13H188', brand_name=u'Melorem 7.5', classification_name=u'Human Medicinal Products', common_name=u'Meloxicam', dosage_form=u'Tablets', product_strength=u'7.5mg', registrant=u'Remedica Limited', registrant_country=u'CYPRUS', manufacturer=u'Remedica Limited', manufacturer_country=u'CYPRUS', expiry_date=u'05-01-2019'), results(sn=u'3', certificate_no=u'TAN 00,2246 P01X FAR', brand_name=u'Diminazen', classification_name=u'Veterinary Pharmaceutical', common_name=u'Diminazene + Phenazone', dosage_form=u'Powder for solution for injection ', product_strength=u'555 mg/g + 445 mg/g', registrant=u'Farvet Laboratories B.V', registrant_country=u'THE NETHERLANDS', manufacturer=u'Farvet Laboratories B.V', manufacturer_country=u'THE NETHERLANDS', expiry_date=u'27-09-2020'), results(sn=u'4', certificate_no=u'TAN 00,2075 J01D FAR', brand_name=u'Penstrep 20/25', classification_name=u'Veterinary Pharmaceutical', common_name=u'Procaine BenzylPenicillin + Dihydrostreptomycin', dosage_form=u'Suspension for injection ', product_strength=u'250 mg/ml + 200 ml', registrant=u'Farvet Laboratories B.V', registrant_country=u'THE NETHERLANDS', manufacturer=u'Farvet Laboratories B.V', manufacturer_country=u'THE NETHERLANDS', expiry_date=u'27-09-2020'), results(sn=u'5', certificate_no=u'TAN 00,2076 J01A FAR', brand_name=u'Tridox 20', classification_name=u'Veterinary Pharmaceutical', common_name=u'Oxytetracycline', dosage_form=u'Injection', product_strength=u'216 mg/ml', registrant=u'Farvet Laboratories B.V', registrant_country=u'THE NETHERLANDS', manufacturer=u'Farvet Laboratories B.V', manufacturer_country=u'THE NETHERLANDS', expiry_date=u'27-09-2020'), results(sn=u'6', certificate_no=u'TAN 00,1820 D01A GLE', brand_name=u'Supirocin', classification_name=u'Human Medicinal Products', common_name=u'Mupirocin', dosage_form=u'Ointment', product_strength=u'2 %w/w', registrant=u'Glenmark Pharmaceuticals Limited', registrant_country=u'INDIA', manufacturer=u'Glenmark Pharmaceuticals Limited', manufacturer_country=u'INDIA', expiry_date=u'22-06-2018'), results(sn=u'7', certificate_no=u'TAN 00,4282 J03B GLA', brand_name=u'Septrin', classification_name=u'Human Medicinal Products', common_name=u'Sulfamethoxazole+Trimethoprim', dosage_form=u'Tablets', product_strength=u'400 mg + 80 mg', registrant=u'Pharmacare Limited', registrant_country=u'SOUTH AFRICA', manufacturer=u'Eva Cosmetics', manufacturer_country=u'EGYPT', expiry_date=u'12-01-2019'), results(sn=u'8', certificate_no=u'TAN 00,4470 J02A HOE', brand_name=u'Candazole', classification_name=u'Human Medicinal Products', common_name=u'Clotrimazole', dosage_form=u'Cream', product_strength=u'1 % w/w', registrant=u'Hoe Pharmaceuticals SDN BHD', registrant_country=u'MALAYSIA', manufacturer=u'Hoe Pharmaceuticals Sdn Bhd', manufacturer_country=u'MALAYSIA', expiry_date=u'01-06-2019'), results(sn=u'9', certificate_no=u'TZ12H146', brand_name=u'Mazit', classification_name=u'Human Medicinal Products', common_name=u'AZITHROMYCIN', dosage_form=u'Capsules', product_strength=u' 250mg', registrant=u'Neopharma', registrant_country=u'UNITED ARAB EMIRATES', manufacturer=u'Neopharma', manufacturer_country=u'UNITED ARAB EMIRATES', expiry_date=u'22-04-2022'), results(sn=u'10', certificate_no=u'TAN 05,068 N02A CLA', brand_name=u'PROVIVE', classification_name=u'Human Medicinal Products', common_name=u'Propofol', dosage_form=u'Injectable Solution', product_strength=u'', registrant=u'ELDA International DMCC', registrant_country=u'U.A.E', manufacturer=u'', manufacturer_country=u'', expiry_date=u'31-12-2019'), results(sn=u'11', certificate_no=u'TAN 05,691 A03B SHA', brand_name=u'Spasmo', classification_name=u'Human Medicinal Products', common_name=u'Homatropine methyl Bromide', dosage_form=u'Syrup ', product_strength=u'2 mg/ml', registrant=u'Shaphaco Pharmaceuticals Industries', registrant_country=u'Republic of Yemen', manufacturer=u'Shaphaco Pharmaceuticals Industries', manufacturer_country=u'Republic of Yemen', expiry_date=u'02-10-2020'), results(sn=u'12', certificate_no=u'TAN 05,153 N04B CLA', brand_name=u'Sedoz', classification_name=u'Human Medicinal Products', common_name=u'Midazolam', dosage_form=u'Solution for injection ', product_strength=u'1 mg/ml', registrant=u'ELDA International DMCC', registrant_country=u'U.A.E', manufacturer=u'Claris Injectables Limited', manufacturer_country=u'INDIA', expiry_date=u'05-06-2020'), results(sn=u'13', certificate_no=u'TZ 15 V 0012', brand_name=u'Hepaturyl', classification_name=u'Veterinary Pharmaceutical', common_name=u'Magnesium + Sodium', dosage_form=u'Powder', product_strength=u'44.5%+25%+25%+5.0%', registrant=u'LAPROVET ', registrant_country=u'FRANCE', manufacturer=u'SOGEVAL', manufacturer_country=u'FRANCE', expiry_date=u'18-09-2019'), results(sn=u'14', certificate_no=u'TZ12H015', brand_name=u'Brunes-200', classification_name=u'Human Medicinal Products', common_name=u'Ibuprofen', dosage_form=u'Tablet, Film-coated ', product_strength=u'200 mg', registrant=u'Nestor Pharmaceuticals Limited', registrant_country=u'INDIA', manufacturer=u'NESTOR PHARMACEUTICALS LIMITED', manufacturer_country=u'INDIA', expiry_date=u'13-12-2021'), results(sn=u'15', certificate_no=u'TAN 06,190 A10B MIC', brand_name=u'Diapride', classification_name=u'Human Medicinal Products', common_name=u'Glimepiride', dosage_form=u'Tablets', product_strength=u'2mg', registrant=u'Micro Labs Limited', registrant_country=u'INDIA', manufacturer=u'Micro Labs Limited', manufacturer_country=u'INDIA', expiry_date=u'21-03-2021'), results(sn=u'16', certificate_no=u'TZ14H010', brand_name=u'Biodroxil 500mg Capsules', classification_name=u'Human Medicinal Products', common_name=u'Cefadroxil', dosage_form=u'Capsules', product_strength=u'500mg', registrant=u'Sandoz GmbH', registrant_country=u'AUSTRALIA', manufacturer=u'Sandoz GmbH', manufacturer_country=u'AUSTRIA', expiry_date=u'06-01-2019'), results(sn=u'17', certificate_no=u'TZ 17 H 0235', brand_name=u'Repoitin 2000', classification_name=u'Human Medicinal Products', common_name=u'Erythropoietin', dosage_form=u'Solution for injection ', product_strength=u'2000 IU/0.5ml ', registrant=u'Serum Institute of India Private Limited', registrant_country=u'INDIA', manufacturer=u'Serum Institute of India Private Limited', manufacturer_country=u'INDIA', expiry_date=u'10-09-2022'), results(sn=u'18', certificate_no=u'TAN 05,486 A10A ELI', brand_name=u'Humulin 70/30', classification_name=u'Human Medicinal Products', common_name=u'Insulin', dosage_form=u'Suspension for injection ', product_strength=u'100 IU/ml', registrant=u'Eli Lilly Export SA', registrant_country=u'SWITZERLAND', manufacturer=u'Lilly France S.A.S', manufacturer_country=u'FRANCE', expiry_date=u'02-08-2020'), results(sn=u'19', certificate_no=u'TAN 00,4452 C03C COS', brand_name=u'Frusemide', classification_name=u'Human Medicinal Products', common_name=u'Frusemide', dosage_form=u'Tablets', product_strength=u'40 mg', registrant=u'Cosmos Limited', registrant_country=u'KENYA', manufacturer=u'Cosmos Limited', manufacturer_country=u'KENYA', expiry_date=u'25-06-2024'), results(sn=u'20', certificate_no=u'TZ13H170', brand_name=u'NovoMix 30 FlexPen', classification_name=u'Human Medicinal Products', common_name=u'Insulin aspart', dosage_form=u'Solution for injection ', product_strength=u'100 U/ml', registrant=u'Novo Nordisk Pharma Gulf FZ - LLC', registrant_country=u'UNITED ARAB EMIRATES', manufacturer=u'Novo Nordisk', manufacturer_country=u'DENMARK', expiry_date=u'06-06-2018')]
```

Now, each row can be accessed by attribute:

```
print([i.brand_name for i in final_results])
```

Output:

```
[u'Trabilin', u'Melorem 7.5', u'Diminazen', u'Penstrep 20/25', u'Tridox 20', u'Supirocin', u'Septrin', u'Candazole', u'Mazit', u'PROVIVE', u'Spasmo', u'Sedoz', u'Hepaturyl', u'Brunes-200', u'Diapride', u'Biodroxil 500mg Capsules', u'Repoitin 2000', u'Humulin 70/30', u'Frusemide', u'NovoMix 30 FlexPen']
```

To scrape all pages with table, you can gather the `selenium` `a` tag object links, and then iterate over each and scrape the data:

```
from collections import deque
pages = []
full_links = deque(d.find_elements_by_class_name('paginate_button'))
while full_links:
   link = full_links.popleft()
   try:
     link.click()
     table_results = [i.text for i in soup(d.page_source, 'lxml').find_all('td')]
     new_results = table_results[12:]
     final_results = [results(*new_results[i:i+12]) for i in range(0, len(new_results), 12)]
     pages.append(final_results)
     full_links.extend(d.find_elements_by_class_name('paginate_button'))
   except:
     pass
```

Comment: I tried this code and at the 3rd page am getting an exception saying "raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.StaleElementReferenceException: Message: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document"

Comment: Unable to read VR Path Registry from C:\Users\Jaxparow\AppData\Local\openvr\openvrpaths.vrpath and sometimes it terminates at page no 4.....is my system faulty because I copied and paste your codes above

Comment: @JAXPAROW95 Have you installed [chromedriver](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads)? If you have not, complete the installation and pass the full path to the driver to the class `Chrome`. If you have, the path you posted does not look like the the path to the chromedriver. You will need to find the file and copy the path. Please see my recent edit for an example of how to pass the driver pass to the class.

Comment: ok I did add chrome to the path ('/Users/Jaxparow/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python35/chromedriver.exe')//This is a location i saved my chromedriver and still the same it opens first page the cmd terminates the python code itself